# How to set animation in pushReplacementNamed

Tags: flutter, animation

Two screen movements are being done through pushReplacementNamed.

```
Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/screen_b');
Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/screen_a');
```

What I want is that the animation behaves in reverse when the screen to `screen_b` goes back to `screen_a`.

Now it keeps moving in only one direction. (From right to left)

I am wondering if there is a way other than push and pop.

Answer (score 0):

use CupertinoPageRoute

```
Navigator. pushReplacementNamed(
                context,
                CupertinoPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => yourpage(),
                ));
```

Comment: He will not achieve `back` effect if he replace the route. This will move him only in one direction.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that you need to use the following in `scree_a`:
`Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/screen_b');`

In `screen_b` you need just pop if you want the back ainmation:
`Navigator.pop(context);`

And when you create your route, use `CupertinoPageRoute`:

```
CupertinoPageRoute(
            builder: (_) => ScreenA/B())
```